# I have a recurser issue trying to apply mapReduce on MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm  trying to apply mapReduce on MongoDb and each time I run the query I get the output below

```
db.Accidental_Drug.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.ID, 1);
    }, 
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values)
    }, 
    {  
        query: {
            DeathCounty: "NEW HAVEN"
        }, 
        out: "gender_totals" 
    } 
)
```

**Output**:

```
{ 
    "result" : "gender_totals", 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: If you set the out parameter to write the results to a collection, the mapReduce command returns a document in the above form. You need to query the output collection specified to get your results i.e. run the query `db.gender_totals.find({})` after the mapReduce operation.

Comment: The aggregation alternative follows: `db.Accidental_Drug.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$ID", value: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $out: "gender_totals" }
])` or to get the results inline  `db.Accidental_Drug.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$ID", value: { $sum: 1 } } }
])`

Comment: thanks for answering i already used this db.gender_totals.find({}) . but in case i want to find female dead in a specific city  grouped by female how can i write using map reduce function .

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include some sample documents from the `Accidental_Drug` collection (i.e. the input) and your expected output/desired result? You can redact any sensitive data if you so wish but preserve the schema so that we can help you with the query.